# Reaction of Phenolic acids

Tags: acid-base, heat

I'm puzzled as to what can happen to phenolic acids when they are heated. (Chemistry, not health or food science) How do they dehydrate? Do they form anhydrides? Also, is it possible for the carboxylic acid part to form an anhydride with an ortho phenol group (given that the COOH group is on a sufficiently long alkyl chain).

Comment: That would be an ester, not an anhydride.